# includes() not matching strings when iterating with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, break, nodelist

I have this simple for loop that is supposed to break and run a function (name_display) if it matches a string (trackName) inside of another string (url). The track_list is a Nodelist of A tags with 'data-url' being an attribute containing a path to a file. This seems easy enough, but it's just iterating over the whole list (track_list) and never breaks to run the function. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

```
let trackName = "track2";
console.log(trackName);

let track_list = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (let i of track_list) {
     console.log(i);
     let url = i.getAttribute('data-url');
     console.log(url);
     if (url.includes(trackName)) {
         name_display(i);
         break;
     }
     else {
     continue;
    }
};
```

UPDATE: As requested, this is the output from the console. Assuming trackName = "track2", this is what prints:

```
"track2"

<a href="#" data-url="path/to/track1">Track1</a>
"path/to/track1"

<a href="#" data-url="path/to/track2">Track2</a>
"path/to/track2"

//Loop should break here

<a href="#" data-url="path/to/track3">Track3</a>
"path/to/track3"

...etc
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant HTML and the `name_dispalay` code.

Comment: includes should work here.

Comment: Include the real use case for verifying

Comment: @spgeise can you add `console.log(trackName, url)` just below `let url = ...` and update your question with the console output?

Comment: You’ll need to add some logging output of a real run of this. Logging trackName and url at each iteration.

Comment: I don't know if it is just here or in your code but you doesnt have a close key for for iteration. Also maybe you should check if url exist. Here i let you some working codepen: https://codepen.io/Motoralfa/pen/LYZydvy. Check if it can help you

Comment: i tried locally and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This code was inside of a document load listener. I didn't mention that in the question because I didn't think it was relevant. In fact, I specifically wanted this to execute once the page is fully loaded. However, when I moved it outside the event listener, it works fine.